# Passing an object from a detail disclosure button segue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, uistoryboardsegue

How can I pass an object from a detail disclosure tap to a detail view controller? Are there any recommendations or quick fixes for this? Ideally I want to create a method like this:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showDetail" sender:self passObject:object];
```

The reason is that 'prepare for segue' seems to only get called when I press the cell before the detail disclosure indicator. How would I create a method like the above to create the effects of prepare below?

```
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    id object = [_objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [[segue destinationViewController] setDetailItem:object];
}
```

I already attempted to create a subclass of UIStoryboardSegue like so but encountered two issues.

```
@implementation masterToDetail
-(void)performSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString*)identifier sender:(id)sender passObject:(id)object{
    [self.destinationViewController setDetailItem:object];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:identifier sender:sender];
}

-(void)performSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString*)identifier sender:(id)sender{
 //What code should go here? Issue one   
}

-(void)perform{
    //Second issue, the compiler will crash and say I need to override perform.
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed the issue by ditching the subclass of segue idea completely. I deleted the custom segue and made a push segue (**from the tableviewcontrollre**) to my detail view controller. I then created an instance variable `NSIndexPath* _ipath;` and my code goes as follows:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    _ipth = indexPath;
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showDetail" sender:self];
}
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"prepping");
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
        NSLog(@"in if");
        id object = [_objects objectAtIndex:_ipth.row];
        [[segue destinationViewController] setDetailItem:object];
    }
}
```

This lets prepare for segue do it's work for the correct cell.

Comment: I think that is the fastest i've ever seen anyone ask and then answer their own question.

Comment: I was determined to fix it and had been spending quite a while on it before I thought to ask. xD

Comment: You could always provide the cell or indexPath as the sender too. Then you don't have to create an ivar for it either.

Comment: How do you hook up a segue from the table view controller to you detail view controller in interface builder??

Answer (score 1):

1. open storyboard
2. select Master view Controller - Master
3. select Segue from UITableViewCell to Detail View Controller - Detail
4. open attributes inspector
5. identifier ->  masterToDetail   write

Comment: How does this allow passing an object reference from the master to the detail view controller?

Comment: @Douglas It doesn't - you do that in prepareForSegue:sender

Answer (score 0):

You can simply right-click on the Table View Cell, and then ctrl-drag from accessory action.